# Feature naming conventions

Tags: notation, feature-engineering, software

I'm curious to know what others tend to see as a suitable naming convention for model features or variables, particularly as they relate to their use and reference in software applications.

For instance, given two inputs: **age** and **income**, we could construct features around various transformations and discretizations of their individual raw values, as well as capture their interaction in a number of ways.

Realizing that we want to make these names concise yet descriptive, would the following seem reasonable? Are they too verbose?

- gt_100k_income
- is_missing_income
- lg10_income
- ge_20_lt_25_age
- zscale_age
- ratio_ln_income_ln_age
- ...

Is it worth trying to (explicitly or implicitly) denote the return type of a feature value?  How about naming a feature that is derived from say 5 or more other features?

Comment: Do you mean convention for naming in a program only, or will there be a meta-data document as well?

Comment: I guess I envision this to be the canonical reference to a particular feature, so within a software program I could see it showing up as a column name in a dataset where it has been computed, or perhaps as a class name in some object oriented language implementation.  That being said I could also see it used in any documentation that gets produced, axis labels on figures, and so forth

Comment: You could shorten the names considerably if you use (1) variable labels and/or (2) a meta-data document.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I think both of these fall more under what I'd term *descriptions*.  Even with these you still need to decide on how you want to format the original name by which you refer to a feature.  With a label or lookup you can take this to an extreme and simply name each new feature as the minimal length unambiguous character string "a", "b", "c", ... and so on but that gives zero information about what that feature represents.  What I'm interested in is what's a good balance in naming conventions (particularly as the number of features scale from the 100's to 1000's)

Comment: Surely some of what you refer to as "features" are levels within a variable. To take income as an example, it makes no sense to have a separate variable for each income category. That means that labels are viable for the categories within each variable, so you can have one variable as Income, and then label the levels within it.

Comment: Sure, but it's pretty common practice in regression modelling to encode these raw input levels as 0-1 valued dummy variables.  Using a continuous input like income may not have been the best example, so instead consider something like gender or country of origin where it would make complete sense to construct features like is_male or is_canadian

Comment: Most of the statistics software does not require that you construct a series of dummy varibles, but rather will do that automatically off your factor levels. You could be making your data more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a lot of variables, at some point you are going to want to figure out what's what, and this will be easier if they are meaningful when put in alphabetical order. You are less likely to group them by whether they are logged or not than whether they are in the same "family".  So, I'd rearrange your example as this:

```
gt_100k_income               income_gt_100k
is_missing_income            income_missing
lg10_income                  income_lg10
age_20_lt_25_age             age_ge_20_lt_25
zscale_age                   age_zscale
ratio_ln_income_ln_age       income_ln_over_age_ln
```

I realize that this is exactly the opposite of what some software does automatically (such as Excel pivot tables or Alteryx Summaries), but Bill Gates isn't right all the time.

It's probably more important to be consistent with your method, than what that particular method is.

Comment: Good points, and I totally agree with your "postfix"-style ordering notation rather than the "prefix" style I had originally.

Answer (score 4):

You're making me think about a kind of Hungarian notation for feature names. Cool.

I like feature names that sort alphabetically on some meaningful domain category. In your example, I'd have all income-related features start with income_.

I also like feature name suffixes that make it obvious what kind of values the feature can take. For instance, if the feature is binary, I may have it end in _is, e.g., income_missing_is. If the feature is a frequency count, it's a _freq, and you immediately know that that will never be less than zero.

If the feature is automatically generated by some special mechanism, e.g., third-party software or some cross-referenced dataset, that is sometimes useful in the feature name. For instance, income_census2010_bracket.

You will want to search and filter feature names, so always use underscore separators and lower case identifiers, never camel case.

Verbosity is not generally an issue; 40-60 characters is fine.

Comment: +1 for the meaningful sort and suffixes - but can you expand on why searching and filtering names requires underscores?  I can search for "camel" in "camelCase" just as easily as "camel_case".  Also, I personally think that verbosity is definitely an issue if you're working with specific variables (rather than classes of variables) - this_is_a_variable_name_about_40_chars_long and I really don't want to type that out all the time...

Comment: Suppose you have features uCase, lCase, camelCase, and capitalCase. What is the search for "lCase" going to return? (This is not impossible to work around, just a gotcha waiting to happen.)

Comment: @Matt Parker: Some of us came of age when there were only capital letters.

Comment: @zbicyclist [Code must have been so beautiful back then...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KellsFol309r.jpg)